# "Can't initialize a new Rails application" regardless of directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a new Rails app using

```
rails new TLC
```

And every time regardless of the folder directory (I've tried everything from Documents to Desktop) I'm in I get this error:

> Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.

When I type:

```
ls -a
```

This is returned:

```
.       ..      .DS_Store   R9      TLC     amplifyu    mymanual
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: did you make a Rails app accidentally in a higher-level folder?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Is there a way to tell?

Comment: cd up the tree looking for a Rails app? Run `rails server` and see if an app spins up?

Comment: why dont u try with a fresh location to ensure "rails new appname" command is working properly? ... after that it will be easy for u to catch problem in this location/directory path.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a Rails application on your PATH (remove it from PATH to fix the problem). Try running `rails server` in an empty directory to confirm that this is the case.